# issue on calling axios in reactJs

Tags: php, reactjs, yii2

I am new to reactJs i need to fetch value from DB using an axios call, But it's showing 404 error
Here is my code

```
axios({
   method: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   url:'http://localhost/projectName/backend/web/category-master/fetch-category',
   responseType: 'json'
    })
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the port you're database is running on

Answer (score 1):

Problem is missing port number after localhost. Please set port number and try again

```
axios({
     method: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     url:'http://localhost:[PORT]/wellnesscc/backend/web/category-master/fetch-category',
     responseType: 'json'
 })
```

For example:

If your backend applciation's port is **5000**, correct version as below:

```
axios({  
         method: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         url:'http://localhost:5000/wellnesscc/backend/web/category-master/fetch-category',
         responseType: 'json'
     })
```

Comment: what is your application's port value? @Don

Comment: 8080 @Ramil Aliyev

Comment: please check this link with postman http://localhost:8080/wellnesscc/backend/web/category-master/fetch-category . If response code is 404, check your application's backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, First check your url route method if it accepting post method.

```
axios.post(url,data, {
headers: {
    'authorization': your_token_if_any,
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
})
.then(response => {
     // return  response;
})
.catch((error) => {
    //return  error;
});
```